# special vlookup in power query

Tags: powerquery

thank you for answering our questions. Look at the picture below. Transfer the rate value appropriately from the first to the second range.

[image]

Comment: Please note that in the second range, the first row is the answer 3500, in the second row the answer is 4000 and the third row is the answer 9500

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello . For example, to find the Rate in the first row of the second range, we need to find a record in the first range that p .Code and SRC are equal, provided that the date in the first range is less than or equal to the date in the second range, then Rate this record to the second range. To be transferred, I have given an example of it in the previous comment

Comment: Please explain what the Date format is in your example

Comment: The format of this date (which is the solar date) is a number. Microsoft does not support solar date , so I'm forced to remove the "/ " mark

Comment: Why is the third row 9500 when two rows match, one with 300 and one with 9500

Comment: Because the date of a row with a Rate of 9500 is smaller than 14010122 and the closest value to it.It could be equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the code below should do what you require.

Read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm.

```
let

//Read in the lookup table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    lookupTable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", Int64.Type}, 
        {"P Code",Int64.Type}, 
        {"SRC", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Rate", Int64.Type}
        }),

//read in data table
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    typeIt2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"Date", Int64.Type},
        {"P.Code", Int64.Type},
        {"Src", Int64.Type}
        }),

//Join the two tables based on PCode and Src
    join = Table.NestedJoin(typeIt2,{"P.Code","Src"},lookupTable,{"P Code","SRC"},"Joined", JoinKind.LeftOuter),

//for each joined subtable
//   Sort descending by date
//   Select only those rows where the date in table 2 is >= the corresponding date from table 1
//   Then extract the first row Rate value (as that will be the closest to the date in table 2)
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(join, "Rate", each Table.SelectRows(Table.Sort([Joined],
        {"Date",Order.Descending}),(t)=> t[Date] <= [Date])[Rate]{0}, Int64.Type),

//Remove unneeded join table column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Joined"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Lookup Table***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Hello, this is exactly the code I wanted. Absolutely true and concise and professional